# rails 4 activerecord relation pagination after filtering by permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using thinking sphinx as my search database, and after I search, I need to filter the results based off of if a user has access to see each result or not. I have a method like, current_user.can_see? that returns true/false. This works fine, however, no matter how I try to loop over the relation, it has to turn it into an array in order to filter/remove the results. This essentially breaks the pagination, total count, total pages, etc.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, or a different approach to paginating a filtered result set?

EDIT: Result set is coming back from a ThinkingSphinx search.

Comment: Why don't you use cancan? - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: Because cancan would require me to show all results, but disallow access to them if a link to that item is clicked. I want to just not show the result entirely.

Comment: You can show only the results that a user has access to - see https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records

Comment: Ah, I did read about that, but the results I'm getting are from a Thinking Sphinx search so this approach doesn't work since cancan just uses a scope.

Comment: turns out that TS returns an array and not an activeresource::relation. So I can just delete_if on the array. It messes with the count for the pagination but i guess it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using will_paginate.

When you have an array and not a collection, the only thing you have to do is to initialize in your app will_paginate in order to work for arrays.

You need to provide an initializer (for instance `config/initializers/will_paginate.rb`) that will only contain this line:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

And there you go. It is working.